# Can I instantiate a class from a method within another class? (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, class, instantiation, irb

I've redone the question and included the full code for both files. In the touch_in method I am trying to instantiate a Journey class in the variable called 'journey'.

```
require_relative 'journey'

class Oystercard

  MAXIMUM_BALANCE = 90

  MINIMUM_BALANCE = 1

  MINIMUM_CHARGE = 1

  def initialize
    @balance = 0
    @journeys = {}
  end

  def top_up(amount)
    fail 'Maximum balance of #{maximum_balance} exceeded' if amount + balance > MAXIMUM_BALANCE
    @balance += amount
  end

  def in_journey?
    @in_journey
  end

  def touch_out(station)
    deduct(MINIMUM_CHARGE)
    @exit_station = station
    @in_journey = false
    @journeys.merge!(entry_station => exit_station)
  end

  def touch_in(station)
    fail "Insufficient balance to touch in" if balance < MINIMUM_BALANCE
    journey = Journey.new
    @in_journey = true
    @entry_station = station
  end

  attr_reader :journeys

  attr_reader :balance

  attr_reader :entry_station

  attr_reader :exit_station

  private

  def deduct(amount)
    @balance -= amount
  end

end
```

The Journey file is as follows:

```
    class Journey

  PENALTY_FARE = 6

  MINIMUM_CHARGE = 1

  def initialize(station = "No entry station")
    @previous_journeys = {}
  end

  def active?
    @active
  end

  def begin(station = "No entry station")
    @active = true
    @fare = PENALTY_FARE
    @entry_station = station
  end

  def finish(station = "No exit station")
    @active = false
    @fare = MINIMUM_CHARGE
    @exit_station = station
    @previous_journeys.merge!(entry_station => exit_station)
  end

attr_reader :fare

attr_reader :previous_journeys

attr_reader :entry_station

attr_reader :exit_station

end
```

I think that the 'touch_in' method should create a 'journey' variable that I called methods on, such as 'finish(station)' or 'active?' etc. When I attempt to do this in IRB I am given the following error:

```
2.6.3 :007 > journey
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from /Users/jamesmac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        3: from /Users/jamesmac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        2: from /Users/jamesmac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from (irb):7
NameError (undefined local variable or method `journey' for main:Object)
```

I'm aware that much of the code above is sloppily written and there are probably other bits, beside the 'journey' issue, where it's just incorrect. Please let me know if this is the case, the more I'm told the better.

Apologies to anyone who attempted to help me on my first attempt, as I say I'm still getting used to SO and was trying to make the post easier to read.

Comment: The title is meant to say 'Can I instantiate a CLASS from a method within another class'.

Comment: Yes, that should work. Isn't it? What happens instead? Do you get an error? An unexpected result?

Comment: @PaulM You can edit your question by clicking on the edit link just below it. I have edited your title for your this time. As for your question, please click on edit and add what exactly doesn't work. Do you get any errors and backtraces? Is something not working as expected (what are you expecting, what happens instead)?

Comment: Could you add what doesn't work as expected? What is the expected behaviour and how does the actual behaviour differ from that?

Comment: @PaulM : You can not `require` two files mutually. By the time `Oystercard#touch_in` is executed, Ruby must have seen the definition of `Journey`. The simplest way to do this is to `require` the file containing the definition of  `Journey` right before `class Oystercard`.

Comment: Thanks for the help regarding the title, I'll keep that in mind! With regards to the error I get the following: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from /Users/jamesmac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        3: from /Users/jamesmac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        2: from /Users/jamesmac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from (irb):7
NameError (undefined local variable or method `journey' for main:Object)

Comment: So in short it just hasn't (or doesn't seem to have) defined the variable 'journey' despite me writing that line in the method touch_in. 
-
To give a bit of context on the whole situation, I'm taking a course on Ruby and one of the challenges is to create a virtual Oystercard. I've now reached the point where classes need to talk to each other and my interpretation of that is that methods from one class can impact other classes. I might be way off here so please let me know if I am.

Comment: @user1934428 In my Oystercard file the first line is: require_relative 'journey' and the second is 'class Oystercard'. The journey.rb file is the one that defines Journey, so I think I'm already doing what you have suggested, unless I've read your message wrongly.

Comment: @PaulM : Then please update your question: The sentence _Both files have require_relative (other file)_  is then wrong, because your journey.rb certainly does not require your oystercard.rb.

Comment: @PaulM : You are not showing us the complete code, because you say that the error message complains about "undefined ...  journey", but the word _journey_ does not occur anywhere in the code you posted, except at the left of an assignment statement (and this can not be the reason for your error message).

Comment: @user1934428 Have done, thanks! Oystercard now requires Journey but Journey no longer requires Oystercard.

Comment: @user1934428 Apologies. I was trying to be succinct and keep my question easy to read. I'll copy over the full code for both files, though the error message has already been copied in full, as I received it from IRB. Is there a way for me to specify that it is code in the comment box like there is when I wrote out the question for the original post? I'm wary it will look horrendous and be hard to read if I just copy the code into a text box.

Comment: @user1934428 
`2.6.3 :007 > card.touch_in('london')
 => "london" 
2.6.3 :008 > journey
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from /Users/jamesmac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        3: from /Users/jamesmac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        2: from /Users/jamesmac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from (irb):8
NameError (undefined local variable or method `journey' for main:Object)`

As you can see, it says that I haven't defined it. I can't fit either file into a textbox.

Comment: @PaulM : I can't see any `require` statement in your posting, and please don't post stacktraces in a comment, but edit your posting instead. You need to provide a minimum reproducible example of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Journey
    # ...
    def initialize
        puts "Journey initialized"
      # ...
    end
    # ...
  end


require_relative 'journey'

class Oystercard

    def initialize
    end
    # ...
    def touch_in(station)
      journey = Journey.new
      # ...
    end
  end

  Oystercard.new.touch_in("station")
```

> stack_question$ ruby oystercard.rb
>
> Journey initialized

It works fine - are you having some issue with this that is beyond the scope of the question?

Comment: Hello! I've reworded the question to give more information about what my problem is, thanks for helping!

Comment: @PaulM From your IRB snippet above, you're calling the variable 'journey' out of context.  This variable is scoped (local) to `touch_in` method.  You cannot call that variable outside of that method's context.  If you want to do so, you'll need an instance variable - `@journey = Journey.new`